# How to auto login with OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn

OpenVPN v5. ask about password in every connection try, so I want to automate this process. I created file `password.txt` with username/password and added line `auth-user-pass password.txt` to .ovpn config file, but client still ask me for password. What's wrong?

.ovpn file:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote ***** 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
auth-user-pass password.txt
ca ca.crt
cert *****.crt
key *****.key
ns-cert-type server
tls-auth ta.key 1
comp-lzo
verb 3
route-method exe
route-delay 2
```

password.txt:

```
login
password
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/818345/why-is-an-authentication-file-accepted-in-the-config-file-and-not-on-the-command

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I put the config file in a wrong folder. The 'OpenVPN/config' wasn't good for my case, beacuse there was a folder for my company. So I moved the password.txt to the 'OpenVPN/config/CompanyName' folder, and now it works fine for me.